# Unable to receive custom IQ from sender using Smack 4.1 library

Tags: android, smack

I have been trying to send custom iq to client but getting error called "unavailable service".Error type which I've got while sending is "Cancel".I looked for the solution for this kind of error type and found it has to do with not to use full jid but in my code as you can see,i am using full jid.Could anyone help me for this please?

Here is the code i am using.

```
public class CustomIQ extends IQ {

String mMyData;

public CustomIQ(String mydata) {
    super("list", "test:namespace");
    this.mMyData=mydata;
}

@Override
protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) {
    xml.rightAngleBracket();
    xml.element("myData", mMyData);
    return xml;
}

}


Custom provider class



public class CustomIQProvider extends IQProvider {

    @Override
    public Element parse(XmlPullParser parser, int initialDepth) throws Exception {
        String data="nothing";
        // Start parsing loop
        int eventType = parser.next();
        outerloop:
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    String elementName = parser.getName();
                    if ("myData".equals(elementName)) {
                        data = parser.nextText();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (parser.getDepth() == 3) {
                        break outerloop;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
        return new CustomIQ(data);
    }
}


Finally i send packet like this.

    enter code here

 CustomIQ myIq = new CustomIQ("test data");
        myIq.setType(IQ.Type.get);
        myIq.setTo("aman@attriaman-android/Smack");
        try {
                mConnection.sendPacket(myIq);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!